# Why is Gluon control CardPane not found when mvn gluonfx:nativerun?

Tags: gluon

Here's the FXML file:

```
<?import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.CardPane?>
<?import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.mvc.View?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<View fx:id="myView" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="335.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.mydomain.view.MyPresenter">
   <center>
      <BorderPane prefHeight="591.0" prefWidth="322.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <center>
            <CardPane fx:id="cardPane" prefHeight="465.0" prefWidth="333.0" />
         </center>
      </BorderPane>
   </center>
</View>
```

If I `mvn gluonfx:run` then it works fine. I see the CardPane. I can add cards to it. I see it update its list of cards as expected.

But if I then try to `mvn gluonfx:nativerun` I fail with **ClassNotFoundException: com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.CardPane**

Here's an excerpt of the commandline callstack:

```
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
[Wed Jul 21 09:59:25 MST 2021][INFO] [SUB] com/mydomain/view/myView.fxml
[Wed Jul 21 09:59:25 MST 2021][INFO] [SUB] 
[Wed Jul 21 09:59:25 MST 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
[Wed Jul 21 09:59:25 MST 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2949)
[Wed Jul 21 09:59:25 MST 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processImport(FXMLLoader.java:2793)
[Wed Jul 21 09:59:25 MST 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processProcessingInstruction(FXMLLoader.java:2758)
[Wed Jul 21 09:59:25 MST 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2624)
[Wed Jul 21 09:59:25 MST 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
[Wed Jul 21 09:59:25 MST 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2516)
[Wed Jul 21 09:59:25 MST 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.airhacks.afterburner.views.FXMLView.loadSynchronously(FXMLView.java:91)
[Wed Jul 21 09:59:25 MST 2021][INFO] [SUB]  ... 21 more
[Wed Jul 21 09:59:25 MST 2021][INFO] [SUB] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.CardPane
[Wed Jul 21 09:59:25 MST 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.oracle.svm.core.hub.ClassForNameSupport.forName(ClassForNameSupport.java:71)
[Wed Jul 21 09:59:25 MST 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:212)
[Wed Jul 21 09:59:25 MST 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(FXMLLoader.java:3017)
[Wed Jul 21 09:59:25 MST 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:3006)
[Wed Jul 21 09:59:25 MST 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2947)
```

Comment: Use `mvn gluonfx:runagent` first so you can identify what classes are required. See https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_gluonfxrunagent

Comment: I want to add that I do not fail to run the Gluon Sample projects as both run and nativerun. But none of the sample projects are using the CardPane UX control.

Comment: @JoséPereda I see the documentation passage for gluonfx:runagent - "If needed, this goal should be executed before the others, and requires the user intervention to discover all reachable classes, by going through all possible scenes, views, dialogs, menus…​". I tried that, clicking through the displayed app at runtime. Then proceeded to build it further to gluonfx:nativerun. But at nativerun, still same ClassNotFound error. How do I proceed? Do I need to buy the LTS1 license for further support?

Comment: `runagent` generates some config files under `META-INF/native-image`, you should be able to find them and search for the CardPane control in the reflection file. Nonetheless you can add `com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.CardPane` directly to the `reflectionList`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @JoséPereda for nudging me where to go look next. New questions came up along the way but I finially got the app working in native run mode.

However, I then realized my noob mistake. I had forgotten to keep going back to the project pom file to update the reflectionList of the gluon plugin. So, I undid the messy fix with underlying config files and then just updated as follows below. I show you the platform widgets I needed to mention per the stacktrace feedback I was seeing. I also listed my own classes but don't bother showing those here too.

```
            <artifactId>gluonfx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${gluonfx.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <reflectionList>
                    <list>javafx.scene.control.DatePicker</list>
                    <list>com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.CardPane</list>
```